# Distributed Algorithm for Minimum Cost Maximum Matching in General Graphs

Tags: algorithms, reference-request, distributed-systems, matching

What are the fastest distributed algorithms for minimum cost maximum matching in **general graphs**?

I found two papers that talk about *approximation* algorithms but I want algorithms that solve the problem exactly.

- [Paper 1](http://www.tik.ee.ethz.ch/file/56a191df06b8e92299baba226e930e3d/disc04a.pdf) - Distributed Weighted Matching, Mirjam Wattenhofer, Roger Wattenhofer
- [Paper 2](http://arxiv.org/abs/cs/0410047) - Simple Distributed Weighted Matchings, Jaap-Henk Hoepman, 2004

I am okay with any model of distributed computing as long as the algorithm solves the problem exactly.

Comment: Can you define "best"?  What is the evaluation metric?  Also, we expect references to fulfill the minimal scholarly requirements and be as robust over time as possible. Please take some time to improve your post in this regard. We have collected some advice [here](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/a/1201/).

Comment: For the LOCAL model of distributed computing, the answer is pretty boring: brute force solves the problem in $\Theta(n)$ rounds, and this is trivially optimal. Probably this is not what you are looking for, so perhaps you could try to specify your requirements in more detail?

Comment: @JukkaSuomela could you elaborate on this brute force algorithm?

Comment: @BanachTarski: Gather everything ($O(n)$ communication rounds), solve locally by any centralised algorithm (0 communication rounds). Lower bound: a long path is enough to show that even if you don't have weights, you will need $\Omega(n)$ rounds to find a maximum matching.

Comment: @JukkaSuomela Hmm, that confuses me further. Even though the final step takes just one round, that doesn't tell us anything about how much processing power is actually being used. I can even say that a centralized processor can solve the Travelling Salesman Problem with 0 communication rounds.

So I guess I want the best algorithm in terms of total number of operations performed per process in the system

Comment: @BanachTarski: Please edit your question and specify the model of computing you are interested in, then. Apparently you are _not_ "okay with any model of distributed computing". :)

Comment: @JukkaSuomela yes I will clarify some concepts with my professor and edit the question then :)